# UIDate comparing two dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am comparing two dates in this way:

```
NSDateFormatter *df= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"  dd : MM : yyyy"];

NSDate *dt1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dt1=[df dateFromString:TheDate];

NSDate *Date=[NSDate date];
NSLog (@"DATE CURRENT: %@ DATE 2 %@", Date, dt1);

if ([Date compare:dt1] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"Date is later than date2");

} else if ([Date compare:dt1] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"Date is earlier than date2");
    [postsToBeDeleted addObject: textmessage];

} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");
}
```

The NSLog gives me:

```
DATE CURRENT: 2013-02-05 21:37:54 +0000 DATE 2 2012-01-04 23:00:00 +0000
```

But it is absolutely clear that the current date is far ahead of the dt1 date, and still I get NSLog(@"Date is later than date2");. Why is this?

Comment: note, that this line `NSDate *Date=[NSDate date];` isnt needed (and without ARC a leak). Do `NSDate *dt1=[df dateFromString:TheDate];` instead.

Comment: Ok, and to get the current date, so i don't need to do NSDate *Date =[NSDate date]

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong line `NSDate *dt1=[df dateFromString:TheDate];` instead of `NSDate *dt1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dt1=[df dateFromString:TheDate];`

Comment: to get the current date `NSDate *now=[NSDate date];`. and you should learn the naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how `-compare:` works for NSDate instances. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-compare_) say:

> If:
>
> - The receiver and anotherDate are exactly equal to each other, NSOrderedSame
> - The receiver is later in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedDescending
> - The receiver is earlier in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedAscending.

In this case, the receiver is `Date`, and `anotherDate` is your `dt1`. `Date` is later in time than `dt1`, so you get `NSOrderedDescending`. (This is actually the situation your log statements imply; I'm a little uncertain as to where the confusion is.)

Comment: And so,how can I compare not the time but the actual date? Day, month, year? If I understood correctly NSOrdered... Refers to the time and not the date?

Comment: @user2014474, either create dates with same time, or create date componetnts without times

Comment: @user2014474, what do u mean?

Comment: Should I replace the compare with erlier date? And later date?

Comment: @user2014474: those orders refer to the **entire date objects**, day, month, and year included. Anything in 2013 will compare NSOrderedDescending to anything in 2012. If you want to compare **just times**, maybe take a look at NSDateComponents?

Comment: If I want to remove the time, which I don'd need, will that compare the actual date?

Comment: @user2014474, you should check the documents and existing threads for how to create dates with identical times or how to create NSDateComponents.

Comment: Ok, but it is clear that I don't want times, only the date... So i'll google: how to remove NSDate time

Comment: @user2014474, YEAH, that's a start!

Comment: @user2014474: I'm sorry, that wasn't clear to me. I think you're on the right track now, though!

Comment: @user2014474, but actually you should be aware, that you dont want to remove the time but set it to the same. and just out of experience: choose a time around noon. than you avoid daylight saving time and leap second gotchas.

Comment: Their's only 1 problem. I can't set the time for the current date because its the real time...

Comment: Mmmmm I found something interesting here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916392/removing-time-components-from-an-nsdate-object-using-objective-c-cocoa

Comment: the day, that no-one is asking for comparison of nsdate objects, [this site](http://hasthelargehadroncolliderdestroyedtheworldyet.com) will return **YUP.**

Answer (score 0):

please let me quote you some interesting thing:

> If:
>
> - The receiver and anotherDate are exactly equal to each other, NSOrderedSame
> - The receiver is later in time than anotherDate, **NSOrderedDescending**
> - The receiver is earlier in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedAscending.