# Comparing NSDates in objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

I have an 2 `NSDates`, a `startdate` and `enddate`. These dates have the following format.

```
startDate = 2013-02-22 12:00:00 +0000; endDate = 2013-02-25 13:00:00 +0000;
```

Now I want to compare these dates. Therefore I've this code.

```
if([event.startDate isEqualToDate:event.endDate]){
     NSLog(@"event %@ is in the same day",event.title);
}else{
     NSLog(@"event %@ is NOT in the same day",event.title);
}
```

But the problem is that it always gets in the else-statement. I want that if the startDate and endDate are in the same day,month and year they give me the first `NSLog` else they give me the second `NSLog`

Any help?

Comment: Remove the time elements from the dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916392/removing-time-components-from-an-nsdate-object-using-objective-c-cocoa

Comment: You are turning the strings into dates with an NSDateFormatter ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
if ([event.startDate compare:event.endDate]==NSOrderedSame)
{
    // The same
}
else
{
    // Not the same
}
```

---

**EDIT :** 
And now that I've noticed (@trojanfoe's *correct* comment) : make sure the time is equal too, or just remove it from your `NSDate` objects.

Comment: isEqualToDate: method detects sub-second differences between dates. If you want to compare dates with a less fine granularity, use timeIntervalSinceDate: to compare the two dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *startDateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:startDate];
    NSDateComponents *endDateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:endDate];
    NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:startDateComponents];
    NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:endDateComponents];

    if([startDate isEqualToDate:endDate])
    {
        NSLog(@"event %@ is in the same day",event.title);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"event %@ is NOT in the same day",event.title);
    }
```