# Need assistance regarding NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I only want date like "29-10-2014" with no time so i did this

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *sDate = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

If I log the `sDate` I am getting perfect result. But I dont want `NSString` I want date object, to do that here what I did is

```
NSDate *theDate = [df dateFromString:sDate];
```

Now I am getting `2014-10-29 19:00:00 +0000`
I only want `29-10-2014`.

Comment: can you tell me why you want something like this? when ever you want date or time from NSDate, you can make a dateformatter and simply use it.

Comment: there are related posts on this, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916392/removing-time-components-from-an-nsdate-object-using-objective-c-cocoa

Answer (score 1):

This is because `-[NSDate description]` returns you full formatted date.

You can swizzle NSDate's `- (NSString *)description{}` and return something that you want.
*Note that this is a very bad practice*

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSDate (CustomDescription)

+ (void)load
{
    swizzleInstance(@selector(description),
                    @selector(description_m),
                    [UIViewController class],
                    [self class]);
}

static void swizzleInstance(SEL originalSl, SEL swizzledSl, Class originalCl, Class swizzledCl) {
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(originalCl, originalSl);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(swizzledCl, swizzledSl);
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
}

- (NSString *)description_m
{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    return [df stringFromDate:self];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution

you are passing string sdata in nsdate,rather pass nsdate object like this

```
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    NSDate *last=[dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
    NSLog(@"last==%@",last);
```

Comment: but he written in question i don't want string object i want object of NSDate.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use NSCalender class to get year, month and date components. NSDate class will always be represented in GMT.

Use

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
[calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
```

Check this article too. Use properties to retrieve value from NSDate
http://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString* reqDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];
NSLog(@"reqDate: %@",reqDate);//reqDate: 30-10-2014
```

Comment: I am also doing same but my date object is from array and its not working for me :(.