# Need assistance regarding converting string to date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
- (void) dateConverter{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[self dates]objectAtIndex:0], [times objectAtIndex:0]]; // string = 01-10-2014 11:36 AM;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    NSLog(@"dateFromString = %@", date); // 2014-10-01 18:36:00 +0000

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSLog(@"dateFromString = %f", timeInterval); // 1412188560.000000
}
```

I am converting the `string` to actual date object, but I am getting different behavior

> string = 01-10-2014 11:36 AM

is actual value I am trying to convert but getting this

> 2014-10-01 18:36:00 +0000

what is wrong with it?

Comment: Looks perfectly normal to me.

Comment: Did you see my answer on your previous post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646455/need-assistance-regarding-nsdateformatter/26646882#26646882

Comment: Swizzling is a last resort solution, in this case all that is needed is to use a date formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a display issue.

You are using the default date formatter to print the date (NSLog used the description method).

The time is displayed in UTC (GMT) and it looks like you are in timezone -0700. The time is being displayed in timezone offset 0000.

The date/time in the system is based on the GMT time, that way times can be compared across timezones and everywhere on Earth the time is the same in the system at the same time.

Use a date formatter to get the date/time in the format you want.

Example code:

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-10-2014 11:36 AM";
NSLog(@"dateString = %@", dateString);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"dateFromString = %@", date);

NSString *displayDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"displayDate = %@", displayDate);
```

Output:

> dateString = 01-10-2014 11:36 AM
>   dateFromString = 2014-10-01 15:36:00 +0000
>   displayDate = 01-10-2014 11:36 AM

Note: You can supply your own date format to get exactly the format what you want.

Comment: I did this NSLog(@"date: %@", [date description]); but result is same :(. Ans I also "po date" in console but result is same.

Comment: Yes, because `NSLog` uses the `description` method. Apple displays the date the way they want to, in GMT (UTC). You are not in the GMT timezone. Use your own date formatter, see the addition to the answer.

Comment: Sir you are marvelous. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @S.J seems you got it from second time, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646455/need-assistance-regarding-nsdateformatter/26646882#26646882

Comment: @zaph Sir if I am trying to convert "date" in time interval I am getting same issue of time zone, how can I fix that?