# NSPredicate matching SELF IN date without time components

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nspredicate

I am wanting to compare dates in an `NSPredicate` when using an `NSFetchRequest` in `Core Data`. I am using:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@ AND dateFound == %@", self.set.events, filterDate];
```

`filterDate` is an `NSDate` object that has the time components set to 00. See: [Removing time components from an NSDate object using Objective C/Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916392/removing-time-components-from-an-nsdate-object-using-objective-c-cocoa)

`events` is a relationship in `Core Data`, and I am needing to check the `dateFound` attribute of the `Event` object that is in that relationship, which is an `NSDate` object.

The issue here is that the `dateFound` attribute is stored in `Core Data`, and since I need to use a predicate with `SELF IN` I cannot modify the `dateFound` data and strip its time components.

**Do I have any other options here?**

Comment: can you show your json format i.e response

Comment: You can try using range in your predicate with 2 dates that have respectively minTimeComponent and minTimeComponent.